# How to replace your Pythonic For Loops with Map and Filter?

Tags: python, for-loop

In the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I was trying to replace and reduce a simple for-loop including if clause unsuccessfully after I read this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-replace-your-python-for-loops-with-map-filter-and-reduce-c1b5fa96f43a) by Jonathan Hsu for a [The Decent game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-tPMY9wdE8). The For loop is as follows:

```py
import sys
import math

# Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
# the standard input according to the problem statement.


# game loop
while 1:
    max = 0
    imax = 0
    for i in range(8):
        mountain_h = int(input()) # represents the height of one mountain, from 9 to 0. Mountain heights are provided from left to right.
        if mountain_h > max:
            max = mountain_h
            imax = i

    print(imax)
```

Based on Jonathan Hsu article I tried to replace `for loop` by `map()` and `if-clause` by `filter()`as follows:

```py
from functools import reduce

# game loop
while 1:
    m = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    max = 0
    imax = 0
    
    u = map(lambda n: mountain_h = int(input()) and print(imax), m)
    r = filter(lambda n: mountain_h > max, n)
    s = map(lambda n: max = mountain_h and imax = i, r)
  # s = reduce(lambda acc, m: acc + n, r)
```

Any inputs to shed light on the realization of this replacement will be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't doing a mapping or filtering operation. If you wanted a functional approach here, without imperative loops,  might use `reduce` or recursion. But it just looks like you are getting the `max`.... so maybe just use `max`.

Comment: `map` and `filter` are both used to create an iterable from an iterable. It seems like you simply want to find a number though, so I don't think `map` and `filter` are appropriate tools here.

Comment: Also, you still have a `while 1` which i very imperative...

Comment: Guys, I was wondering If I could use `map()` & `filter()`. Nevertheless, I'm open to using other proper tools like `reduce()` via calling `from functools import reduce`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga At the start of each game turn, I'm given the height of the 8 mountains from left to right. By the end of the game turn, I must fire on the highest mountain (it means I need to find the while `max` and update the variable) then pass its index as an output to print (from 0 to 7). BTW I'm not sure what's the role of `while 1` here.

Comment: Note that doing assignments within the lambda body of `map` very likely does not accomplish what you want.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I see I was inspired by that article and try to follow & replace them after  I read the abovementioned article. That's why I left a post here to get more input in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The part you aren't capturing is that your loop is implicitly producing a sequence of calls to `input`; that's a job for the two-argument form of `iter`, which will call `input` until it returns a given value. `iter(input, None)` can return an infinite number of values, since `input()` will never return `None`, but you can short-circuit that using `itertools.islice` to limit it to 8 calls.

Once you have the inputs (or rather, an iterator that will *produce* your inputs), you can use `enumerate` to tag each input with its sequence number and use `max` (with an appropriate `key` function) to find the largest value and its index.

```
from itertools import islice

while 1: 
    my_inputs = map(int, islice(iter(input, None), 8))
    imax, m = max(enumerate(my_inputs), key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    print(imax)
```

Piece by piece:

1. `iter(input, None)` is an infinite stream of calls to `input()`.
2. `islice(..., 8)` only yields the first 8 of them.
3. `map(int, ...)` calls `int` on each value. (Warning: this won't catch a `ValueError` raised by a non-integer input. There's no functional way to deal with the exception.)
4. `enumerate(my_inputs)` turns a stream like `3, 7, 2` into `(0, 3), (1, 7), (2, 2)`.
5. `max(..., key=lambda x: x[1])` on the above sequence returns `(1, 7)`, because `7` is the largest second element of all the tuples.

You might also find the use of `operator.itemgetter(1)` cleaner than an explicit lambda expression as the `key` argument to `max`.

---

A more Pythonic version of the same approach would use a generator function to produce the stream of integer values for `max`/`enumerate` to iterate over. It also makes it easier to handle input errors. For example:

```
def eight_integers():
    for _ in range(8):
        while True:
            try:
                x = int(input())
            except ValueError:
                continue
            yield x

imax, m = max(enumerate(eight_integers()), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Of course, you could also have `eight_integers` yield an index and an integer itself, eliminating the need to use `enumerate`.

Comment: Note that your max call will return the index of the first maxiumum rather than the last as in the code in the question

Comment: Thanks for your input, is there any possibility to use filter() instead of if-clause as they did in [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-replace-your-python-for-loops-with-map-filter-and-reduce-c1b5fa96f43a)?

Comment: Good point, though it might not matter, or the inputs are guaranteed to be unique integers. If it is an issue, you can use `reversed` to iterate over the inputs in reverse order to compensate (at the cost of no longer using O(1) space).

Comment: @Mario As pointed out in the comments, you aren't doing a filter operation here; it simply isn't appropriate or applicable here.

Comment: `filter` requires you to apply the *same* predicate to each element of the stream, and for finding the maximum of the stream, the predicate can change while you iterate.

Comment: @Chepner May I ask you also explain what is the role of `while 1:` in this scenario? what would be if we omit it? and why it is `1` here?

Comment: Beats me; I just kept it from your example. I assumed there was some reason you would want to repeatedly input another batch of 8 values and find the max of each separately. (`while True:` would be a better way to write an infinite loop; Python has boolean constants, and doesn't need to use plain integers in their place.)

Answer (score 0):

So, `map` is to update elements within a list, `filter` is to remove elements, and `reduce` is to collect/aggregate... You are never filtering or mapping data, only gathering input, then compaing against a running `max`, which would be a use-case for `reduce`, but still unncessary given Python's `max()` function.

If you want Pythonic code for this, then it seems you really want a list comprehension, followed by a method that gets the max value & index within that list

```
values = [int(input()) for i in range(8)]
_max = max(values)
imax = len(values) - 1 - values[::-1].index(_max)  # assuming you want the last index
```

But note that this is effectively replacing one loop with 3 and has nothing to do with DRY principles

Comment: Kindly your code doesn't return back index of the maximum value in the list if you run it.

Comment: It does if you print it... Not sure what you mean

Comment: Your solution works good but it hasn't met the requirement I asked for in the question. I wanted to learn to replace for-loop by map & filter alternatively like in the [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-replace-your-python-for-loops-with-map-filter-and-reduce-c1b5fa96f43a). You believe that it's not suitable for my case?

Comment: I do not. Same sentiments from others in the comments

Comment: That article is a very narrow use-case. You cannot replace all loops with those functions

Comment: I see what you mean and all inputs helped me to change my mind and not generalize every approach I see in online articles in Medium or Towards science quickly. Thanks, sir again.